# To solve the expectation problem of unbouned distribution, is there any proper numeriacal integration method for it?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to make integration for unbounded distribution, there are two singularity points in the integrand. It's an improper integration. It can not be solved by the normal method. Is there any proper numerical method for this problem? here is the integrand, the r_c, beta are non-negative parameters and epsilon_1 and epsilon_2 is in the interval of [-infinity, -(2/3)beta].

[image]

Thank you advance for your help.

Comment: It would help to see what the integrand is.

Comment: Thank you. The integrand is a little complicated, I've attached it in my answer. Please click it and read it in my answer.